# How to send GET request with axios to jwt-auth?

Tags: laravel-5, axios, jwt

In  vue/cli 4 / vuejs 2.6.10 / vuex,3.0.1 app I make axios request

```
axios.get(apiUrl + '/personal/user_groups/'+user_id )  /
   .then((response) => {
```

to backend app(Laravel 5/jwt-auth) with routes in jwt.auth group :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth',  'prefix' => 'personal', 'as' => 'personal.'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('user_groups', 'API\PersonalController@user_groups');
```

and got error :

```
"error":"UNAUTHORIZED_REQUEST"
```

I found a way of sending the POST request with config parameter and token parameter, which I got on successful login:

```
let config = {
    withCredentials:true, 
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
}
axios({ url: apiUrl + '/personal/user_groups', data: {user_id:user_id, token: this.getters.token}, method: 'POST', config : config })
    .then(response => {
```

But if there is a way to send the GET request and I made in the topic start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution in adding Authorization parameter to request headers

```
settingCredentialsConfig.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + this.getters.token;
axios.get(apiUrl + '/personal/user_groups/' + user_id, settingCredentialsConfig)
    .then((response) => {
```

where settingCredentialsConfig is defined in settings.js as

```
export const settingCredentialsConfig = {
    withCredentials:true, 
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
}
```